# C printing shapes: Unable to add back slash

Tags: c

I am trying to print this shape:

```
###/\###
##/  \##
#/    \#
/      \
\      /
#\    /#
##\  /##
###\/###
```

This is the code I have written:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int totalRows = 5;
    int row, colSpace, colStar, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 2 * totalRows - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("n");
    for (row = 1; row <= totalRows; row++)
    {
        for (colSpace = totalRows - row; colSpace >= 1; colSpace--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        for (colStar = 1; colStar <= 2 * row - 1; colStar++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (colSpace = totalRows - row; colSpace >= 1; colSpace--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("n");
    }
    for (row = totalRows - 1; row >= 1; row--)
    {
        for (colSpace = 1; colSpace <= totalRows - row; colSpace++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        for (colStar = 1; colStar <= 2 * row - 1; colStar++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (colSpace = 1; colSpace <= totalRows - row; colSpace++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("n");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 2 * totalRows - 1; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}
```

By the above code we get the figure without the dashes. How do I get them?I've tried adding them but I am unable to get them at the needed place. And I am unable to insert the back-slash into the body of printf()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To get a literal back-slash you need to *escape* it, like you with e.g. newline.

Comment: `void main()` -> `int main(void)` , `printf("n")` -> `printf("\n")`, to print a backslash use `"\\"` (double backslash)

Comment: The shape is symmetrical, I suspect you could get away with less code by having a function (taking a `row` number) drawing the upper half (i.e. the three inner `for` loops plus printing a newline) and then calling that twice - the second time, you're reversing the order in which the rows are counted. Maybe it would even be possible to just hav a function which draws one quadrant and then call that four times.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Thats a possible approach but now since we have the code, I think in order to obtain the back slashes and slashes we could just add a few characters here in there. where exactly is what i want to know. If possible can you show your approach in code?

Comment: @L887: Added an answer including some code to illustratemy suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw two issues:

1. there is no code for printing either forward-slashes or backslashes in your code. I think you should add a `printf("/");` or `printf("\\");` before/after the loops which print the spaces.
2. To print a newline, you need `printf("\\n");` -- note the backslash.

That being said, I mentioned in a comment to your question that the shape is symmetrical so it might be able to reuse the code for painting the upper half to draw the lower half. I mentioned that some function which prints a single `row` would be useful. Here's what I had in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Could have been passed to printRow() instead of using a global variable. */
int totalRows = 4;

void printRow( int row, char leftSlash, char rightSlash )
{
    int i;

    /* A couple of variables to aid readability. */
    int totalWidth = totalRows * 2;
    int numSpaces = row * 2;
    int numHashes = totalWidth - numSpaces - 2;

    for ( i = 0; i < numHashes / 2; ++i ) {
        printf( "#" );
    }
    printf( "%c", leftSlash );
    for ( i = 0; i < numSpaces; ++i ) {
        printf( " " );
    }
    printf( "%c", rightSlash );
    for ( i = 0; i < numHashes / 2; ++i ) {
        printf( "#" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < totalRows; ++i ) {
        printRow( i, '/', '\\' );
    }
    for ( i = totalRows - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
        printRow( i, '\\', '/' );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how the program first calls `printRow` with increasing values, and then with decreasing values for the lower half. The only thing which changes is the kind of slash to use for the left/right side.

Comment: This is way better than my approach. Thanks for the effort:)!

Answer (score 3):

A backslash in C (and many other languages) is a special "escape" character. For example - \n means a newline.
If you want a literal backslash, you need to escape it too - with a backslash - so `"\\"` will encode the single slash.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Could you also tell me where should I place the back-slashes and the normal slashes exactly;i.e in which loop to get the required result?